# How to confirm two sets contain the same vectors in any order?

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting, permutation

Say if I have two sets of vectors, for example:

$$v_{1}=((0,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1),(1,1,1))$$

$$v_{2}=((0,1,0),(1,1,1),(0,0,0),(0,0,1))$$

I want to find a way of verifying that both $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ contain the same vectors, regardless of order.

**I'm not sure how to do it, below are attempts that did not work:**

```
v1={{0,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1},{1,1,1}}
v2={{0,1,0},{1,1,1},{0,0,0},{0,0,1}}
```

```
TrueQ[OrderlessPatternSequence[v1]==OrderlessPatternSequence[v2]]
```

```
Equal[Permutations[v1],Permutations[v2]]
```

```
Intersection[v1,v2]
```

Comment: Should the multiplicity of the vectors match as well? If it doesn't matter then `Union[v1] === Union[v2]` should be okay.

Comment: As in can there be duplicates of the same vector or am I misinterpreting "multiplicity of the vectors"?

Comment: From the examples at  [`OrderlessPatternSequence`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/OrderlessPatternSequence.html) you can use `MatchQ[v1, {OrderlessPatternSequence[Sequence@@v2]}]`

Comment: `Union` will sort as well as delete the duplicates. Yes, you are interpreting it correctly. I guess the ambiguity exists as you used the word `set` instead of `list`.

Comment: I see! So I am inputting a list into mathematica but I am wanting it to recognise it as a set so that index positioning is not a barrier? Is that the main difference between ````set```` and ````list```` here?

Comment: My understanding is that Mathematica does not have a `Set` construct but only a `List` construct. If, however, you use functions intended for sets, such as `Union`, `Intersection`, `Complement`, then these functions will sort (since order does not matter in a set) and will delete duplicates (since a set contains unique elements only).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way:

```
Sort@v1==Sort@v2
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 4):

You might want `ContainsExactly`:

```
ContainsExactly[v1, v2]
```

although it will ignore multiplicities.

Answer (score 3):

#### 1.

A slight variation of creidhne's suggestion in comments:

```
sameOrderlessPatternQ = MatchQ[{OrderlessPatternSequence @@ #}]@#2 &;

sameOrderlessPatternQ[v1, v2]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

#### 2.

```
Internal`ComparePatterns @@ (OrderlessPatternSequence @@@ {v1, v2})
```

> ```
> "Identical"
> ```

#### 3.

```
GeneralUtilities`EquivalentPatternQ @@ (OrderlessPatternSequence @@@ {v1, v2})
```

> ```
> True
> ```

#### 4.

```
GeneralUtilities`AllSameBy[Sort] @ {v1, v2}
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Using `SymmetricDifference` which came with V 13.1

```
v1 = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}};
v2 = {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};

SymmetricDifference[v1, v2] === {}
```

(* True *)

From the documentation:

*"SymmetricDifference[list1, list2] gives the sorted list of elements that are in list1 or list2 but not in both."*

If we change the third element of `v2` to

```
v2 = {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
```

we get

```
SymmetricDifference[v1, v2]
```

{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}}